# Overriding a class method in subclass Java

Tags: java, oop

I have a class which has 2 methods:

```
class A {
  public methodA();
  public methodB();
}
```

I have two other classes B & C, which have Class A as its members:

```
class B {
   A a;
   B(Config config) {
      a = config.getA();
   }
}

class C {
   A a;
   C(Config config) {
     a = config.getA();
   }
}
```

However, in class C I want to implement a different way of method B. I guess I  need to override the method, but then I will need to make class A as an abstract class. Is that correct? Is there a different way to approach this

Edit: I am not directly creating a new instance of A. I am getting it from a helper class.

Comment: `a = new A() { public void methodB() {  ..... } };`

Comment: *I am not directly creating a new instance of A. I am getting it from a helper class.* Well then you can't override its methods.

Answer (score 1):

> I will need to make class A as an abstract class

No just make sure that methodB has not been declared to be final, since final methods cannot be overridden. You can override the method "inline" by creating a new anonymous class from the A class within your C code:

```
class C {
    A a;
    C() {
        a = new A() {
            @Override
            public void methodB() {
                // .... code goes here
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1692342: Your code is pseudo-code, it's "kind-of sort-of" code. If you're making changes and adjusting conditions, please post *real* compilable code, code where methods have return types, where you show your actual helper method. At this point I now have no idea what your code looks like or where you're stuck. Please help us.

Comment: updated how I am getting class A. Does the edit help

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in simple way.

In Java, if you need method to be overriden, it is done in a child class.  However as you get the instance of `A` from someone else (the `config`), you have no way to control what is the class instantiated by `config`.

There are some alternatives:

If the new `methodB` can be done without knowing the internal of `A`, you can create a wrapper of `A`:

```
class C {
   static class CustomA extends A{
       A a;
       public CustomA (A a) { this.a = a; }

       @Override
       public void methodB() {
           a.methodB();
           a.otherMethod();
       }
   }
   A a;
   C(Config config) {
     a = new CustomA(config.getA());
   }
}
```

---

Another alternatives is to change your `Config` to allow creation of other `A` child classes dictated by the caller of `getA()`.  This can be done by misc way like Reflection or initialization of already-created `A` instance, and etc.

---

Another alternative is to extract logic of `methodB` out to a strategy.  So you can replace the strategy to whatever you want.  Check out Strategy pattern in GoF design pattern.